# Node.js Embed being sent before field is added, how can I make sure the embed is built completely before it is sent using Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Below is the code starting from the part what is being left out if it exists (Potential Cyno). It is essentially checking to see whether someone has lost a ship with a specific item on their ship. However, it is not always reliable. It appears as though the embed is being sent before it is even done getting whether or not the person has the item on a ship they have lost and embedding that. Sometimes it will include this field, others it will not.

Is there a better way to go about making sure this is checked prior to the rich embed being sent?

```
  let cynoLosses = [];
  snekfetch.get(losses).then(l => {


    for (var c = 0; c < l.body.length; c++) {
      var item = l.body[c].victim.items;

      for (var items = 0; items < item.length; items++) {


        if (item[items].item_type_id === 21096 && cynoLosses.length < 1) {
          cynoLosses.push(l.body[c].killmail_id);
         console.log(l.body[c].killmail_id);
          embed.addField("POTENTIAL CYNO", "https://zkillboard.com/kill/" + cynoLosses[0] + "/");
        }
      }
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Try adding a small setTimeout

Comment: Can you post the part of the code that sends the embed?